# How to refrence Excel in .Net application?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2008, using

It's showing me an error at the below highlight area

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Tried to add a reference but there are already two references like

**Microsoft Office 5.0 Object Library    1.0      c:\Program file\Microsoft office\office\XL5EN32.OLB
Microsoft Office 9.0 Object Library         1.3      c:\Program file\Microsoft office\office\XXCEL9.OLB**

I added reference to EXCEL .exe but it throwed error i'e., a refrence to 'c:...\excel.exe' cannot be added.please make sure that the file is acessible and tha is a valid assmbly or COM Component.'
Please suggest if I need to add any references or what needs to be done....

Comment: please post error detail

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx